# Multiline regex blank line delimiters,

Tags: regular-expression

I have a program which prints out data in blocks.
Each block is delimited by blank lines.

I would like to discard most blocks and only keep those blocks that contain something that matches a regex.

I can of course do it with a scripting language or a prgram, but that seems rather crude. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you give some sample input and output?

Answer (score 12):

`awk` and `perl` have a special mode especially designed for that. Called the *paragraph* mode. In that mode, records are paragraphs, that is they are separated by sequences of empty lines.

For `awk`, it's with setting `RS` to the empty string:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/regexp/'
```

With `perl`, it's with `-00`.

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /regexp/'
```

Answer (score 6):

It's usually possible to do this kind of thing fairly easily in `awk`, by setting the *record separator* to a double-newline, and then doing a regex match within the records. For example, if I have

```
block #1
this block doesnt' contain
anything I want to keep

here's a block
with some important stuff

here's another
block of stuff

and another
```

Then

```
$ awk -vRS="\n\n" '/important/ {print}' blocktext.txt 
here's a block
with some important stuff
```

It would be easier to answer definitively if you provided an example.

Answer (score 1):

Running [pcregrep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pcregrep) in multiline mode on @steeldriver's example:

```
pcregrep -Mo '\n\n\K(.|\n)*?important(.|\n)*?(?=\n\n)' file
here's a block
with some important stuff
```

Comment: That wouldn't match on the first and last paragraph though.